# Sending data to serial port using Processing IDE (Debug works but run doesn't)

Tags: text, arduino, processing

I'm trying to read a series of numbers in a text file on my PC then send them to my Arduino board via serial port. The numbers are split by commas and dashes so I perform two loops. Sending a number to the serial port should light the equivalent LED on the Arduino board. The problem is that only the first iteration in the first loop doesn't light the equivalent LEDS in run mode though it does in the debug mode.; other iterations and other loops run flawlessly. There aren't any problems with the hardware 100% for sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
import java.io.*;
int mySwitch=0;
int counter1=0;
int counter2=0;
String [] subtext;
String[] Lines;
Serial myPort;

void setup()
{
//Create a switch that will control the frequency of text file reads.
//When mySwitch=1, the program is setup to read the text file.
//This is turned off when mySwitch = 0
 mySwitch=1;

 //Open the serial port for communication with the Arduino
 //Make sure the COM port is correct
 myPort = new Serial(this, "COM36", 9600);
 myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
 }

void draw()
 {
 if (mySwitch>0)
   {
 /*The readData function can be found later in the code.
 This is the call to read a CSV file on the computer hard-drive. */
 readData("Y:/MyTextFile.txt");

 /*The following switch prevents continuous reading of the text file, until
 we are ready to read the file again. */
 mySwitch=0;
   }
 /*Only send new data. This IF statement will allow new data to be sent to
 the arduino. */

  while(counter1<Lines.length)
   {
 subtext = splitTokens(Lines[counter1],","); 
 counter2=0;
 while(counter2<subtext.length)
     {
 /* Write the next number to the Serial port and send it to the Arduino 
 There will be a delay of half a second before the command is
 sent to turn the LED off : myPort.write('0'); */
 myPort.write(subtext[counter2]);
 counter2++;
      } 
 delay(2000);
 myPort.write('0');
 delay(2000);
 counter1++;
    }
 //If the text file has run out of numbers, then read the text file again in       5 seconds.
delay(5000);
mySwitch=1;
} 

/* The following function will read from a CSV or TXT file */
void readData(String myFileName)
{
 File file=new File(myFileName);
 BufferedReader br=null;

 try
  {
 br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
 String text=null;

 /* keep reading each line until you get to the end of the file */
while((text=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
 /* Spilt each line up into bits and pieces using a comma as a separator */
 Lines = splitTokens(text,"-");
    }
  }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 }catch(IOException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
 try {
 if (br != null){
 br.close();
 }
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please format your code with proper indentation so we can read it? When using debug mode, are you setting a breakpoint anywhere? Is the loop being entered at all, or is it skipping over the whole loop? Why are you using the `delay()` function instead of setting the frame rate?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern. Sorry for the bad formatting; I'll take care of that. Yeah, I set a breakpoint at this line:
     Lines = splitTokens(text,"-");
And in the debug mode, the loop is normally entered and nothing at all is skipped. but in the run mode, the first iteration in the first loop seems to be not executed, I don't know.

Comment: I don't know about the frame rate but the delay works fine with other iterations and even with the first problematic iteration in the debug mode.